# How to adjust hover in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, data-visualization

I have data with 2 categorical and 1 numerical column. I built marikemo chart in `ggplot`, and in order to make it interactive, I used `ggplotly()`.
However, when I move a cursor, hover shows the same information twice:

```
# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)


library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

plt <- data %>% 
  group_by(specie) %>%
  mutate(value = value / sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_col(position="fill", width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value, accuracy = 0.1)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.50),
            color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")

ggplotly(plt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes what comes from `ggplotly` is odd. The tip, sure. The black background? Where did it get that from? Either way, I used `lapply` to determine which traces had either `text` or `hovertext` that contained the word "scale". I chose scale because it was string that only appeared in the tooltip that needed to go away. Then I used `any` as in "is anything true?" and `grepl` to get a true or false response for matches to the string.

```
plt2 <- ggplotly(plt)              # set to object to modify
invisible(lapply(1:length(plt2$x$data),
                 function(j) {
                   txt <- plt2$x$data[[j]]$text
                   htxt <- plt2$x$data[[j]]$hovertext
                   if(any(grepl("scale", txt)) | # any matches per trace
                      any(grepl("scale", htxt))) {
                     plt2$x$data[[j]]$hovertext <<- ""
                     plt2$x$data[[j]]$hoverinfo <<- "none" 
                   }
                 }))
plt2
```

The extra tip is no longer shown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kat, you are 'Guru' of plotly!